# Adjusted p-values across hypotheses with different power?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

Simple question with no simple answer.

Let's say I compute 100 p-values from 100 hypotheses that have similar power (i.e. similar sample size). Now let's say I produce 1000 p-values from a series of hypotheses that are relatively under-powered (i.e. have a smaller sample size for each test). How does one control for multiple hypotheses in this case? Applying a common procedure like Benjamini-Hochberg will fail to take the difference in power into account. I'd be mixing p-values from sensitive tests with p-values from tests that have a higher prior likelihood of resembling a uniform distribution. Is there a way to control for multiple hypotheses among series of hypotheses with severe differences in statistical power?